# Increment value by 1 using Wordpress by pressing button

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, increment

I have a Wordpress website and I want to have a page where if you press a button it increments a stored value by 1. I would prefer for the page to refresh once the button is pressed to show a page with the new integer value.

I am not sure if I should be using PHP and like a txt file to store a data or use mySQL...either way I don't have any idea how to code such a thing! I just want something pretty simple :)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use session of php.

Comment: Hi Mihir, thanks for your response, but could you explain what you mean by this? or tell me where I can maybe learn more. I don't mind doing the hard yards but I am just not an expert :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use jquery code like that. There are many tutorials on youtube that show how to link the jQuery library in html.

You can then put use this code in the html of your page. or if your are using an external javascript then you should enqueue your javascript file in your theme functions.php file like so

```
wp_enqueue_script('your_js_handle', plugins_url('your_js_folder/your_js_file.js',__FILE__) ,array('any_dependency_the_js_file_might_require',false);

add_filter('wp_head','your_function');

function your_function(){
$output = '
var myvalue = 0;
$("#mybuttonid").on("click",function(){
    myvalue++;
    localStorage.setItem("any_name_here", myvalue);
})

if ( localStorage.getItem("any_name_here") ) {
  myvalue = localStorage.getItem("any_name_here");
}
</script>';
echo $output;
}
```

You can then use myvalue to put this as a text in some div tag.
But first you have to have the div id. let say the div id is 'the_text'

**This is the code you should use:**

Then you could write the code like so.

```
wp_enqueue_script('your_js_handle', plugins_url('your_js_folder/your_js_file.js',__FILE__) ),array('any_dependency_the_js_file_might_require',false);


add_filter('wp_head','your_function');

function your_function(){
$output = '
var myvalue = 0;
$("#mybuttonid").on("click",function(){
    if ( localStorage.getItem("any_name_here") ) {
      myvalue = localStorage.getItem("any_name_here");
    }

    myvalue++;
    $("#the_text").text(myvalue);
    localStorage.setItem("any_name_here", myvalue);

</script>';
echo $output;
}
```

For `your_js_handle` you can put any name but do not include spaces.
your_js_handle is the id of the file that will be available in the HTML DOM.

`Plugins_url` is the function you should use if you are working with a plugin.Else
you should use `get_template_directory_uri('your_js_folder/your_js_file.js')`.

`__FILE__`is written with 2 underscores  before and after the word so that is not an error and what `__FILE__` will do is that it will retrieve the relative path of the file you are working with.

`array('any_dependency_the_js_file_might_require',false)` should be used if the javascript file requires any library in order to work. like if your plugin require the jQuery library then you have to use it by stating array('jquery').
if your plugin requires the jQuery library make sure you are  enqueuing it before using it. Wordpress normally comes with a preinstalled jQuery library which is the latest version. To use it just state

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Finally `false` means either you render the file in the footer or the header of your site. In which case you should make sure you are using `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()` as required. If you set it to true, the script is placed before the  end tag.

Comment: A little answer tick would be really awesome. Glad that helped you.

Comment: Updated the code. So your code should run fine now.